# Python remove line containing specific char at the front

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I remove a line from a txt file which start with ">"?

For example, in the txt file, there is about 250k+ lines and if I were to use the code below, it will take quite some time.

```
data = ""
with open(fileName) as f:
     for line in f:
         if ">" not in line:
             line = line.replace("\n", "")
             data += line
```

An example of the txt file is:

```
> version 1.0125 revision 0... # This is the line to be removed
some random line 1
some random line 2
> version 1.0126 revision 0... # This is the line to be removed
...
```

I have tried using `data = f.read()`, it is instant but the data will contain line that start with ">".

Any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: You are not writing your data back to file.

Comment: What do you want to do with this data afterwards? Write it to a new file? Your first code is slow, because the `+=` operator doesn't interact well with (the immutability of) strings.

Comment: If you really want to remove the final `\n` from your lines, note that `line.strip()` is about twice as fast as `line.replace('\n', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing what you want to do with the data afterwards, this should be fast and correct:

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    data = "".join(line for line in f if not line.startswith(">"))
```

If you just want to remove these lines from the file, I would honestly not do it in Python, but in your shell directly, e.g. on Linux:

```
$ grep -v '^>' original_file.txt >fixed_file.txt
```

If you insist on Python, do it on a line-by-line basis:

```
with open(original_file) as f:
    with open(new_file, "w") as g:
        for line in f:
            if not line.startswith(">"):
                g.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The first code works as I need the data to search for the position of the random line without ">" in the file. However, I do not wish to modify the file. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use two files, one for reading, second for appending:

```
with open(fileName, 'r') as f, open(fileName.raplace('.txt', '_1.txt'), 'a+') as df:
     for line in f.readlines():
         if not line.startswith('>'):
             df.write(line)
```

Comment: Firstly you have a typo that suggests that you have not tested this. Secondly, you are unnecessarily reading the whole of the file into memory at the same time. Thirdly, it is not clear why the output file is opened in append mode - what if it already exists?